# Pattern with inner Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking pattern which is similar to code below.

I want know how to create MyComponent.

```
render(){
<MyComponent>
 <MyComponent.Something>
       this children will be rendered
 </MyComponent.Something>

 <MyComponent.Modifier word="hello">
       hi, my name is Kaka
 </MyComponent.Modifier>

 <MyComponent.Whatever>
      WhatEver
 </MyComponent.Whatever>
</MyComponent>
}
```

I really can't find it on google. I would like to create a component that will have children and I will be able to change these children and render inside the component. How is it called?

Comment: You want `<MyComponent>` to control the contents of `<MyComponent.Something>` ?

Comment: The father could accept children who will be components and I will use these micro-components to push various differences in rendering. <MyComponent> is to be re-use component, but some things can be changed, preferably with children, which I will be able to tell the difference.

Comment: "You want <MyComponent> to control the contents of <MyComponent.Something>" --> If I understand you correctly, Yes. Control is too big a word, I want to render in the right place in <MyComponent>

Comment: To my understanding you just want the sub-components to be included within the father component. This is done simply by object assigning: `function MyComponent() {}; function MyComponentSomething() {}; MyComponent.Something = MyComponentSomething;`

Comment: Haha, really easy. :D Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can archive this by using props. Sample code given below. Please check this

You looking for something defferent  please explain briefly, that way I can help you more

```
import Home from "Homepath"
import child1 from 'childPath'
import child3 from 'child3path'
class App {

        handleChange=(stateObj)=>{
            this.setState(stateObj)
            }
            render(){
            <Home>
            <child1 someProps={this.sate.somevalue} handleChange={stateObj=>{this.handleChaange(stateObj)}} />
            <child2 hello="hello" />

            <child2 name={this.state.name} />

            </Home>
            }
            }
```

Comment: Include the code of `Home`, that's what op is looking for i believe.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `props.children`:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  return (
    <>
      {props.children}
    </>
  );
}

function Something(props) {
  return (
    <span>
      {props.text}
    </span>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <MyComponent>
      <Something text={'this children will be rendered'} />
      <div>
        This one too
      </div>
    </MyComponent>
  );
}
```

Nice introduction at: https://codeburst.io/a-quick-intro-to-reacts-props-children-cb3d2fce4891